# Error editing connection Unable to find a connection with UUID ('null')

Tags: networking

When elementary loads the NIC does not have an IP and i need to manuuly configure it every boot.

When trying to edit network connection through settings I get "did not find with UUID "" "

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file /etc/networking/interfaces and put a # in front of EVERY line. This will comment them out. NOTE you will need to use sudo and suggest command

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Next, stop and restart the NetworkManager.service with:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

The start and stop of the network mnager should be two separate command - most easily done on two lines. First enter sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service on one line. Then enter sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service on a new line.

The second way you can edit network connections is to use the network manager tool in terminal:

```
sudo nmtui
```

There you will be able to edit connections and save your changes. After the restart it should remember your settings.